# GeForce GTX970 G1 - Turning off energy save mode

Tags: gpu, nvidia-geforce, powersave

Is there any way to disable low voltage mode in GTX970 Gigabyte G1 GPU (clock goes down to 135 MHz in idle)? I would like to lock GPU at maximum frequency and power level, regardless of current load (idle or stress).

Comment: Not sure if that's possible, but if it is, that'll be a great way to kill the card quickly. Are you able to give the reason(s) you want to run your card this way?

Comment: For some reasons card often stuck on low voltage/frequency after CUDA kernel execution errors. The only way to recover standard performance is to reboot the OS so I am forced to do it over and over after any critical execution error. Turning off power safe mode could possibly eliminate that issue.

Comment: It sounds as though there is a hardware or firmware error with your card. If it is out of warranty, perhaps you could try going back to an earlier driver version?